# At what Java version did HP change the JNI include folder name?

Tags: java, hp-ux

I access an HP-UX box from time to time.  It has Java 1.5, 1.6 and (now) Java 8 installed.  I noticed that, between Java 6 and 8, the JNI include folder changed from $JAVA_HOME/include/hp-ux to $JAVA_HOME/include/hpux.  At what version did this change occur?  This screwed up a few makefiles until I discovered this, but, I now need to support both iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did it the hard way, downloading, installing and ls-ing.  Looks like it changed with the first release of Java 8; Java 7 still uses the old naming convention.  So, at least there's that, it didn't change partway through the lifecycle.